# Motion to target the matching brace/paren in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

So, Vim, like most programming-minded text editors, highlights a matching "scope" character (such as `(` and `)`, `<` and `>`, and `{` and `}`).

I'm wondering, is there a motion to reach that character from the other? Like, with the caret on a `<`, to move to the (highlighted) matching `>`?

I know [action]`t>` or [action]`f>` would accomplish something similar. That's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The motion is: `%`.

Used alone, this jumps between open/close pairs based on the value of the `matchpairs` option.

But angle brackets - `<>` - *aren't* included by default. They may be set based on the `filetype`. The HTML filetype plugin sets it, so if you're opening HTML files you'll be able to use `%` to jump between matching angle brackets. But not for e.g. C++/Java.

To add angle brackets if they aren't jumped when using `%`, use:

```
:set matchpairs+=<:>
```

Now using `%` on angle brackets should jump to the matching bracket.

See `:help 'matchpairs'` and `:help various-motions` - `%` is the first mentioned - for more details.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the <kbd>%</kbd> keystroke does this. See [Moving to matching braces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_to_matching_braces) for more information.